# How to run playbook across multiple environments with their own group_vars?

Tags: ansible

My current ansible structure looks something like this:

```yaml
 - inventory
    - prod
        - prod1
            - hosts.yml
            - group_vars
                - all.yml
        - prod2
            - hosts.yml
            - group_vars
                - all.yml
        - prod3
            - hosts.yml
            - group_vars
                - all.yml
    - nonprod
        - dev
            - hosts.yml
            - group_vars
                - all.yml
        - qa
            - hosts.yml
            - group_vars
                - all.yml
        - uat
            - hosts.yml
            - group_vars
                - all.yml
 - roles
    - main.yml (this isn't accurate just a sample playbook for the question)
```

I'd like to be able to run something like this: `ansible-playbook main.yml -i inventory/prod` and have it automatically cycle through the environments (each with distinct group_vars values).

Currently the command will find the hosts in each environment but not the vars which stops the playbook from running, but if I run `ansible-playbook main.yml -i inventory/prod/prod1` it runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest restructuring your inventory. Ansible looks for the `group_vars` directory adjacent to your inventory files. If you run with `ansible -i inventory ...`, it won't find the `group_vars` file (it will only find it when running e.g. `ansible -i inventory/prod/prod1`).

Consider a layout like this:

```
inventory/
├── group_vars
│   ├── prod1.yaml
│   ├── prod2.yaml
│   └── prod3.yaml
└── prod
    ├── prod1.yaml
    ├── prod2.yaml
    └── prod3.yaml
```

Where each inventory file places hosts into a similarly named hostgroup. E.g., `inventory/prod/prod1.yaml` contains:

```
all:
  children:
    prod1:
      hosts:
        prod1-node0:
        prod1-node1:
        prod1-node2:
```

If we have a variable defined with a different value for each group:

```
$ grep . inventory/group_vars/*
inventory/group_vars/prod1.yaml:location: datacenter1
inventory/group_vars/prod2.yaml:location: datacenter2
inventory/group_vars/prod3.yaml:location: datacenter3
```

And a playbook like this:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: location
```

We can run it against all the hosts (I'm only using two groups here, `prod1` and `prod2`, in order to keep the output shorter):

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -i inventory
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [prod1-node0] => {
    "location": "datacenter1"
}
ok: [prod1-node1] => {
    "location": "datacenter1"
}
ok: [prod1-node2] => {
    "location": "datacenter1"
}
ok: [prod2-node0] => {
    "location": "datacenter2"
}
ok: [prod2-node1] => {
    "location": "datacenter2"
}
ok: [prod2-node2] => {
    "location": "datacenter2"
}
```

Or you can run the playbook against a specific group:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -i inventory -l prod2
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [prod2-node0] => {
    "location": "datacenter2"
}
ok: [prod2-node1] => {
    "location": "datacenter2"
}
ok: [prod2-node2] => {
    "location": "datacenter2"
}
```

In each case, hosts will use the values from the appropriate group_vars file based on their hostgroup.

Comment: Making a test for this now - will it work with subgroups? let's say in each environment I have [group1] and [group2] - can I get those group_vars in directories such as group_vars/prod1/group1.yml?

Comment: Ansible will look in the `group_vars` directory for files or directories named after hostgroups. Remember that your inventory is **flat**, there is no such thing as a "subgroup". A host can be a member of multiple groups. Try out what I've suggested here and see if it answers your original question; if you have followup questions, I would suggest opening a new question showing your updated inventory and what you've tried.